# Radio group selected option not updating ngModel value in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, radio-group, angular-ngmodel

I am new to angularjs and trying to find a solution for the setting a selected value of radio group to the ngmodel.

```
//my.html     

<div ng-controller='controller'> 
 <div class="btn-group" ng-model="option" ng-repeat="arr in dragDropOption">
  <input type="radio" name="optionCorrectOpt" data-ng-model="option" 
    value="{{dragDropOption[$index].text}}">
      {{dragDropOption[$index].text}}
</div>
```

and 
     //mycontroller.js

```
 app = angular.module('app', []);

 app.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
 $scope.dragDropOption = [];
 $scope.option = "not set";

 $scope.dragDropOption = [{
     text: "analog"
 }, {
     text: "isdn"
 }, {
     text: "dsl"
 }];
 //   $scope.option = $scope.dragDropOption[0].text;
});
```

[My fiddle is  here](http://jsfiddle.net/vR2s6/)!

Might be it is repeated question, please help me with sharing already answerd stackoverflow question's link or new answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `arr` inside the loop, so why use `dragDropOption[$index]`?

Comment: @Yoshi it was "arr.text" instead of "dragDropOption[$index].text" It was debugging code on fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `input` change

```
data-ng-model="option"
```

to:

```
data-ng-model="$parent.option"
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vR2s6/3/)</kbd>

Comment: You can also return `$scope.option = $scope.dragDropOption[0].text;`

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$scope.option = "not set";

<input type="radio" name="optionCorrectOpt" data-ng-model="option" 
value="{{dragDropOption[$index].text}}">
```

To:

```
 $scope.radioOption = {};
 $scope.radioOption.selected = "not set"

 <input type="radio" name="optionCorrectOpt" data-ng-model="radioOption.selected" 
value="{{dragDropOption[$index].text}}">
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vR2s6/1/)